# Starting a URI in the background

Tags: batch-file, url, background-foreground

I can't seem to figure out how to open a URI from a [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), whilst keeping the running Command Prompt window in the foreground and in focus.

I've tried using `start "" /b "www.google.com"` but it still moves my browser on top of the Command Prompt.

Comment: One potential workaround is to use another scripting language like JavaScript to switch the focus back to the title of the command window. For example `echo new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell").AppActivate("Open Browser"); > "%tmp%\tmp.js" & %__APPDIR__%cscript.exe //nologo "%tmp%\tmp.js"& del "%tmp%\tmp.js"` where "Open Browser" would be the title of your command window.

Comment: I'd suggest putting a delay with the `timeout` command between starting the browser and executing the command to switch the focus back to the command window.